# Is there a template or basic configuration of the ethereum network to deploy on local machines or VMs?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain

I have ongoing pilot project which shows it could not be run on the `ethereum mainnet`: the business model would fit the cost of deployment and operation. That's why I think of deployment own network on own machine (cloud solutions like `AWS`, `Azure` etc. are not an option too due concerns to delegate core business functional to the 3rd party).

At the moment of writing Ethereum offers `Mainnet` and two `testnets`: `Sepolia` and `Goerli`. A bunch of tools, e.g. `hardhat`, provides local development `testnet`. However, deploying your own testnet on your machine or VMs is out of scope in [the official documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/networks/#private-networks).

There is a collection of available networks https://chainlist.org/ where network like an Aurora is built [from scratch](https://github.com/aurora-is-near/aurora-engine) by implementing ethereum protocols.

The implementation of `ethereum` chain and keeping up with new standards releases is not an option either at least at this stage. Is there an option to deploy own chain with minimum investments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official ethereum repository](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) provides opensource layer which is seems what I am looking for. I haven't checked yet, but its `puppeth` - a CLI wizard that aids in creating a new `Ethereum` network - should help with installation of the new network.

Comment: Here steps for deployment https://github.com/Gelassen/swap and partly automated deployment script https://github.com/Gelassen/swap/blob/feature/blockchain-integration/blockchain/start_nodes.sh